# Facebook Canvas app payment error appear while i was goes to make purchase?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

[image]

See above screenshot there was issues with facebook payment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue with sandbox payment on multiple environment, live payments are working.

I've tested the server webhook via the web payment dashboard and it works.

The current calls are on API 2.4 and also tested with 2.7 still get the same error.

The error started appearing on different account not all at the same time.

I'm continuing my search but hope these information can help to find and solve the issue.

Comment: Found this bug in the tracker : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1825393971117440/